# Python Import affect another import

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
   crawler/
    commands/
       allcrawl.py
       __init__.py
    __init__.py
    items.py
    settings.py
    spiders/
       ekantipur.py
       gorkhapatra.py
       himalkhabar.py
       __init__.py
       __init__.pyc
       kantipurtv.py
       
    test.py
    tests/
       __init__.py
       responses/
          __init__.py
          spiderdir/
              Archive_ekantipur.com.html
       spiderdir_test.py
```

When I try to run the spiderdir_test.py file, then I need a class ekantipurSpider which is in spiders/ekantipur.py, then When I do this

```
from spiders.ekantipur import ekantipurSpider
  File "spiders/ekantipur.py", line 5, in <module>
   from crawler.items import NewsItem
   ImportError: No module named crawler.items
```

Than It shows that I cannot import crawler.items having NewsItem class. What is the main cause of this? Cannot find any solution in whole day.

Comment: Have you installed `crawler` in any way? I found [this article](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/) useful in getting a Python project set up with tests etc.

Comment: I don't have the time for a full-blown answer, so here is the PEP : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/ . My guess is there is a system-wide module installed called crawler, which nameclash with your local one.